# Fastest way to do vector / matrix multiplication with constant matrix

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra

Suppose we have a fixed n x n matrix, call it $B$. What is fastest way to evaluate $v^t B\;v$ over many different vectors $v$?

Since $B$ is a constant matrix, does this allow the number of operations needed to evaluate $v^t B\;v$ for an arbitrary $v$ to be reduced?

Comment: You might want to learn the way Mathematica [interfaces](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/guide/CUDALink.html) with CUDA. In particular, read about the [dot product](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/ref/CUDADot.html) and [loading to memory](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/ref/CUDAMemoryLoad.html). If you load the matrix to CUDA memory, it will be the fastest you can go.

Comment: Floating point matrix multiplication is done using the [MKL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_Kernel_Library) in Mathematica, and it is already very fast.  It's much faster than a naive C implementation, especially for large matrices.  What you can do to speed things up is try reduce the overhead of Mathematica before it calls the MKL, e.g. make sure that B is a [packed array](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array).  Otherwise it's going to be as fast as it can get, unless the matrices are tiny.  Whether CUDA helps depends on your hardware.

Comment: Loading the vectors into the GPU memory might be slower than just doing the math on the CPU.

Comment: You can't get away without at least $N^2$ multiplications. There could be some simplifications if your $B$ is symmetric or if $v$ is a random vector. Perhaps if you described what you were trying to achieve, then we could help you with that.

Comment: Assuming that `v` is a vector of vectors, `v == {v1, v2, ...}`, the direct way is this:  `Table[x.b.x, {x, v}]`.  This is quite fast.  We can improve a bit by doing part of the multiplication in a single go: `r = v.b; Table[v[[i]].r[[i]], {i, Length[v]}]`.  This is a bit faster. I don't know how to do the `Table` part in one go while avoiding unpacking the arrays.

Comment: Thanks,  I think we are looking at n*n multiplications.  When doing it in a c program sometimes you can check which elements of v are 0.  And then you can get away with not having to look at those rows and columns of matrix.  But normal case n^2 multiplies are needed it seems.

Answer (score 5):

If the vectors `v` come one at a time and must be handled that way, as opposed to being collected for batch analysis, then I don't see how you can beat simply `v.B.v`. However, if you can collect them as the rows of a `many` x `n` matrix `V` then `Total[V.B*V,{2}]` is very fast. (If the vectors come "naturally" as the columns of an `n` x `many` matrix `U` then use `Total[U*B.U]`.) However, there may be version and/or platform differences, so YMMV.

Comment: On my machine with Mathematica V9 this is indeed nearly one order of magnitude faster than the `Table` approach.

Comment: Also there are asymptotically fast matrix multiplication methods e.g. Strassen's. But one needs a really big matrix for these to be competitive.